# Angular2 return Observable<Response> from wrapped Html.get

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I need to wait for this observable to return (simplified):

```
assembleOptions(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<boolean> {

    let auth = this._cookieService.get(this.auth);

    if (auth === undefined || auth === null) {
        this._http.get('/someValue').map(x => {
            //do something with x
            return Observable.of(true);
        })
    } else {
        return Observable.of(true);
    }
}
```

This appears to return an `Observable<true>` which doesn't really matter, as I am not using it, I just need to wait for it, then I try to use it within this:

```
public get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
  return this.assembleOptions(options).map(x => {
      return this._http.get(url, this.options);
  });
}
```

Where `this._http` is from

> import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';

Which does not work, it is returning an `Observable<Observable<Response>>`

```
Type 'Observable<Observable<Response>> is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'
```

What am I missing here?  I have tried casting all over the place to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) instead of `map`

```
return this.assembleOptions(options).switchMap(x => {
      return this._http.get(url, this.options);
  });
```

From the [switchMap documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

> Map to observable, complete previous inner observable, emit values

Comment: Thank you for this!  Exactly what I was looking for!